# org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to work with an sql database in my app (For Learning purposes). 
The app can read, insert and delete data about students: firstname,lastname and age.
When I tested it on localHost with wamp it worked great, but after I put the database and the php files on 000webhost, I encountered a problem with *reading* data form the database and extracting it from the json. When I try to do so, it do not succeed and does 'nothing'. The error i printed:

`org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

The insert and delete functions work perfectly.

My code is: 
**android**

```
       public void listClick(View view){
        Log.i("myTag", "listClick");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dataText.setText("trying to show data");

        Response.Listener<JSONObject> jsonListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i("myTag","response is: " + response.toString());
                try {
                    Log.i("myTag","listClickInside");
                    JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("students");
                    Log.i("myTag","listClickInside0");
                    for(int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++){
                        Log.i("myTag","listClickInside1");
                        JSONObject student = students.getJSONObject(i);
                        String firstName = student.getString("firstname");
                        String lastName = student.getString("lastname");
                        Log.i("myTag","listClickInside2");
                        String age = student.getString("age");
                        //  int age = student.getInt("age");
                        Log.i("myTag","listClickInside3");

                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "A:"+firstName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dataText.append(firstName+"|"+lastName+"|"+age+"\n-------\n");

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i("myTag","(catch)response: " + response.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        Response.ErrorListener jsonErrorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("myTag","--listError: "+error.getMessage());
                System.out.print(error.getMessage());
            }
        };

        Log.i("myTag","creating jsonObject Request");
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl,jsonListener,jsonErrorListener);
        Log.i("myTag","created jsonObject Request");


        Log.i("myTag","creating requestQueue");
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        Log.i("myTag", "created requestQueue");
    }
```

the php code:
**showStudents.php**

```
    <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include 'connection.php';

    showStudent();
}
function showStudent()
{
    global $connect;

    $query = " Select * FROM STUDENT; ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $temp_array  = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $temp_array[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("students"=>$temp_array));
    mysqli_close($connect);

}
?>
```

**connection.php**

```
    <?php

define('hostname', 'mysql11.000webhost.com');
define('user', 'a******_user');
define('password', '****');
define('databaseName', 'a****_testdb');

$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, databaseName);
?>
```

Comment: Looks like response doesn't seem to be a valid JSON.. hence the exception.

Comment: Well, I cannot see why it isn't a valid JSON. Just for some background, it worked when my database was on localHost using WAMP, but for some reason it doesn't after I put it on an online web host.